# Media Queries not Working in Tailwind CSS

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

Media Queries in TailWind CSS are not working Well.

*My Code is this*

```html
<img src={MYIMAGE} alt="Test Image" className="h-6 w-8 rounded-md gfold:h-8 gfold:w-14 gfold:rounded-xl sm:h-16 sm:w-24 " />
```

`gfold` -> `(400px)` - A Media Size included by me in the `tailwind.config.js` file. 
`sm` -> `(640px)` - A Default Media Size that Comes with Tailwind.

When Media Size is below `sm` size is correct, But when my screen is greater than the `sm` size the ***Size is not Changing***.

Now what should I do? *Please help me*, I am new to Tailwind CSS.

Comment: Can you re-create your problem in [Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/)

Comment: Here is the [Link](https://play.tailwindcss.com/KAYPfXUSwO?size=332x720)

Comment: And what do you exactly want? Whats the result you want to get?

Comment: I want to change the Image Size when the Screen Size changes. But it is not Happening.

Comment: Breakpoints need to be sorted from smallest to largest to work. Your new gfold class is overriding the default breakpoints that are larger than it. This is explicitly mentioned in the docs along with guidance on what you should do instead when you want to add a small breakpoint https://tailwindcss.com/docs/breakpoints#extending-the-default-breakpoints

Answer (score 5):

First of all with tailwind css, the media queries are used for larger screens, the default css is applied for mobile, so keep that in mind

i would suggest the standard breakpoints defined by tailwind instead of overwriting the config file ,

```css
   <img src={MYIMAGE} alt="Test Image" className="h-6 w-8 rounded-md md:h-full md:w-full" />
```

this will set the picture to full dimensions when screen is larger than 768px.

also make sure when you define a new breakpoint in tailwindcss to add the following to the config file

```js
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')

 module.exports = {theme: {screens: {'gfold' :'400px' ,...defaultTheme.screens},}}
```

you can check how tailwind logic is made with media queries in: https://learnjsx.com/category/1/posts/mediaQueries

Answer (score 1):

To completely replace the default breakpoints, add your custom screens configuration directly under the theme key in your tailwind.config.js:

```
theme: {
    screens: {
      'sm': '576px',
      // => @media (min-width: 576px) { ... }

      'md': '960px',
      // => @media (min-width: 960px) { ... }

      'lg': '1440px',
      // => @media (min-width: 1440px) { ... }
    },
  }
}
```

Any default screens you haven’t overridden (such as xl using the above example) will be removed and will not be available as screen modifiers.

To override a single screen size (like lg), add your custom screens value under the theme.extend key:

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      screens: {
        'lg': '992px',
        // => @media (min-width: 992px) { ... }
      },
    },
  },
}
```